# Searching contacts properly with Postgresql (Thomas or Tom, or misspellings)

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, contacts

I'm not even sure if this is possible. But basically I need a really good way of searching contacts via Postgresql. Example:

```
# I have a contact:
# Name: Thomas Baker
# Company name: Johnson & Johnson

# I would like the following queries to return the above contact:
# Thomas
# Tomas
# Tom
# Johnson & Johnson Thomas
# Bake
```

Basically allow partial matches, closeness matching, and search across multiple fields.

I'm familiar with Postgresql full text searching, but I have no idea how to accomplish the above with it. I'm just looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may use sphinx search engine http://sphinxsearch.com/

Comment: Right, I know about sphinx, solr, etc. I wanted to solve this with postgres if possible.

Comment: Hm, you may try to concatenate name and company name, then create gist index.

Comment: Thanks pavleg. I actually decided to use trigram and do similarity matching. I don't think there is a cleaner solution for doing this in postgresql. Above this, I'd probably need to use solr.

Comment: there is. levenshtein. you need to enable fuzzystrmatch.